# GraphView is not displayed

Tags: android, android-graphview

I tried plotting a line graph using GraphView.
Code used is:

```
if (list.size() > 0) {
        GraphView graph = new LineGraphView(this, "Score");

        GraphViewData[] graphData = new GraphViewData[list.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            graphData[i] = new GraphViewData(i, list.get(i).getScore());
        }
        graph.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(list.size());
        graph.getGraphViewStyle().setNumVerticalLabels(list.size());
        graph.getGraphViewStyle().setGridColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        graph.getGraphViewStyle().setHorizontalLabelsColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greenYes));
        graph.addSeries(new GraphViewSeries(graphData));
        mLayout.addView(graph);
    }
```

But after end of this code execution, screen remains white i.e. nothing draws on screen. Size of list is >0.

xml is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLevelCompleteScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLevelCompleteCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize25" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and mlayout is initialized as:

```
mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you referring to this when you say graph view ? http://www.android-graphview.org/

Comment: Yes, I am referring it

Comment: what is mLayout? please tell us how you are initializing it

Comment: mLayout is Linear layout with vertical orientation, height wrap content. It has 2 text views before this graph view and they are displayed

Comment: edited the ques to include xml and mLayout initialization

Comment: you are not mentioning the size of the graphview anywhere. is it possible to define the graphview in XML , or does it have to be done dynamically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74742/discussion-between-harvey-slash-and-seema).

Comment: perhaps it doesnt supports inside scroll. Woked fine after removing scroll view.

Comment: set a fixed height and width for the graphview view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't supports inside scroll. Worked fine after removing scroll view.